# Git pull says it's up to date but it isnt

Tags: git, git-pull

I have some changes I made from another computer and sent it to remote repository.
When I try to make a `git pull origin <branch>` from home to get those changes it
says  `Already up-to-date` but the changes are not in my computer, the files have not changed.

Why?

**Edit 01:**

When I try `git log`

> commit 10ewwqe9989861ad33335e40188dcab598bc2312
>   Author: Name 
>   Date:   Sun Nov 27 23:46:40 2016 -0200
>       < commit message here >

If I check this commit code/name on bitbucket commits section, I see that THIS commit is one behind than the last commit present in my remote repository.

**Edit 02:**

`>$ git remote -v`

```
origin  https://bitbucket.org/username/repositoryName (fetch)  
origin  https://bitbucket.org/username/repositoryName (push)
```

`>$ git fetch origin`

```
From https://bitbucket.org/username/repositoryName
 * [new branch]      myBranch -> origin/myBranch
```

`>$ git log myBranch..origin/myBranch`

```
commit 0220ff...
Author: John Doe <johndoe@email.com>
Date:   Mon Dec 28 16:43:07 2016 -0200

    Name of my last update to remote repository
```

The log command shows the right last commit, the last one that is in my remote repository and the one I want to bring to my local files... But local files still unchanged.

Comment: When you say origin it loads them, but you are most likely on a local branch. Remove origin and pull a branch that's linked to that remote branch

Comment: did you checkout your branch? git checkout <branch>

Comment: @Dezigo Yes. I checkedout to the same remote branch.

Comment: try to remove your branch and checkout it again. git branch -d <branch> and check out it again . git checkout <branch>. does it work?

Comment: @Dezigo I deleted it, then it checked out back again just fine (is it normal?) i didn't recreated it. But the files still the same.

Comment: please check the last commit - just write: git log

Comment: @Dezigo Interesting thing: The log doesn't show the last update that has been sent to remote repository, it shows one commit behind.

Comment: please try: git fetch origin, and then pull the changes again. git pull

Comment: @Dezigo `git fetch origin` > `git pull origin <branch>`/`git pull`. Still the same ;\

Comment: what about `git pull -f origin <branch>`?

Comment: @Marina-MSFT Same response. `Already up-to-date` and the files remain the same without change =\

Comment: You need to check you remote repo, if you pushed successfully? And if the commit id in remote branch is the same as your local branch?

Comment: @Marina-MSFT I'm using bitbucket and its all good, already verified the files and it's changes. When I try `git show-ref` the *remote/heads* IDs are the same for this branch. But as I said, when I check `git log` the last commit shown is one commit behind than the remote commits.

Comment: What's the `git checkout HEAD` and `git pull origin <branch>`?

Comment: @Marina-MSFT
`git checkout HEAD`> It shows the deleted files and the message: **Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/myBranch**. Git Pull still the same :|

Comment: can you do a `git fetch origin` and then do a `git log <branch>..origin/<branch>` for us and give us the output? Make sure to use only two dots.  Also, what does `git remote -v` show? Does it show unexpected remotes?

Comment: @jbu Thanks ! Already updated the question with the responses... It's weird because now the log shows the right commit but it's not local yet.

Comment: This doesnt fully answer your question but if u wanted to you could now point a branch to 0220ff or even modify the current branch to do so.

Comment: @jbu And how could I do that ? I found some kind of  `--hard reset` but I'm not sure if I should do this.

Comment: Try `git pull origin myBranch:myBranch`. If this can work, I guess the upstream of the local `myBranch` is empty or not `origin/myBranch`.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you did `git pull origin myBranch` already and it didn't work and since you know the most up-to-date commit, you can simply point your branch to that commit (in this case 0220ff): `git reset 0220ff`.  Now run `git log` to verify that you're at the right commit.  As VonC also mentioned, you could do create a branch pointing to the remote myBranch `git checkout -B myBranch origin/myBranch` but I suspect that if the `git pull origin myBranch` didn't recognize the latest change in origin/myBranch, then this might not work either.

I'm still not sure why `git pull origin myBranch` wouldn't work, but it seems like your local machine is aware of the latest change on origin/myBranch, so it should theoretically have 0220ff in its local object store ready for you to point your branch to this location.

Answer (score 1):

> The log command shows the right last commit, the last one that is in my remote repository and the one I want to bring to my local files... But local files still unchanged.

You can reset your `myBranch` to `origin/myBranch` with

```
git checkout master
git checkout -B myBranch origin/myBranch
```

(note the `-B` as `myBranch` already exists)