# Git pull shows "already up to date" but they're wrong

Tags: git, git-pull, git-fetch

DISCLAIMER : There's already [a post that already addresses this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42003838/git-pull-says-its-up-to-date-but-it-isnt) but sadly the author did not find any definite answer.

Here's my issue : **`git pull` shows "already-up-to-date" but they're wrong**

For [a quick 2-min video explaining the issue just here](https://www.loom.com/share/22ccf79c6bd743c39551227f8f29d538).

For written explanation, read below.

Here's the sequence of events :

- On my local machine / locally, I've got two branches : `main` and `F01`
- I added a few commits to F01
- From F01, I `git push` the commits to gitHub
- On my remote repo, I now have two branches too : `origin/main` and `origin/F01`
- Created a PR to merge origin/F01 -> origin/main
- PR merging went successfully well ✅
- Now I want to git pull from main (local) the commits recently added to origin/main
- `git pull` : ❌ "Already up to date"

I already tried:

- `git fetch` : ❌ nothing.
- `git diff main..origin/main` : ❌ nothing, no changes detected
- `git diff main..F01` : there are changes ✅
- `git diff main..origin/F01` : there are changes ✅

Any ideas as to why origin/main can't be updated and sync with the real state of origin/main?

Comment: can you please check git log on local if it has already the commits on your local?

Comment: Can you share with us a link to your git repository? It would also help to see the output of `for branch in main F01 origin/main origin/F01; do echo "$branch: "; git log --oneline -1 "$branch"; done`

Comment: Two small notes here: (1) `git pull` means *run `git fetch`, then run a second Git command* (your choice of second command but the default is `git merge`). I prefer to run both commands myself, to give me a lot more control. If you do this you won't have this particular problem. (2) When `git merge` says "Already up to date" and quits, it really is up to date, even if you don't believe Git. The trick is that it's up to date by *GIt's* standards. You need to know what `git merge` does and when you want to use it and when you want to use something else...

Comment: Note that using the two separate commands doesn't mean you won't still have issues with Git! It's just that by avoiding `git pull` you'll have *solve-able* issues, rather than ones that are really hard to track down because it's not even clear which second command `git pull` is running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of a mate who advised me to use gitHub Desktop, I've found the possible reason of the issue :

[image: default branch is wrong]

Instead of having main or origin/main as my default branch, for some reason (some command I may have accidentally performed), the F02 became the default branch. And I must have created F02 from origin/main. So I suppose @Nikhil was probably right.

Which was very weird because when performing a `git branch` I could only see the following (and no F02 available) :

[image: git branch no F02]

Solution I've found:
I've **locally** merged `local/F01` -> `local/main` and right after that I tried to git reset --hard to remove all the commits I had just added.

As a result : when doing `git diff main..origin/main`, now it worked! ✅
I could see the changes on `origin/main` that were not on `local/main` :)

So I went back to my post to update my post and share my investigation and solution and found your two posts @larsks and @Nikhil.

@Nikhil : sadly I saw your post only after but I bet it would have made it worked cause it looks like the HEAD was detached from `main` or `origin/main`

@larsks : I had already performed your command and indeed : `F01` did show changes ✅ but main/origin did not show any new commits  (for some reason).

Thank you very much for your help  guys and for responding so quickly!

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure which branch you are doing a git pull, anyways it does not matter.

So in some cases, there is a condition where the branch HEAD gets detached or deviated. Which might cause the issue which you mentioned.

So handle this you can try these commands

1. `git rebase master` this will rebase your master to the origin version. master may vary to the main branch also
2. In case you have some other branch you can use the same command with the specific branch name.

   ```
   git rebase your_branch_name
   ```

These commands should work. according to your mentioned issue